# Does calling methods inside methods cause overhead?

Tags: c++

Say I have a class with some method f():

```
class Example
{
  Example();
  ~Example();
  void f();
}
```

Let's say `f()` is only a few lines. Let's also say some other method in `Example` calls `f()` in itself. Would calling `f()` in such case cause overhead, as opposed to simply duplicating its code into wherever it's needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [function inlining](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2LywvCM9/), and let the compiler do it automatically. Nowadays compilers are very aggressive with it.

Comment: But assuming the function doesn't actually get inlined, is there any overhead in a regular function call for the sake of readability?

Comment: Yes there is overhead. But even so, the difference is negligible, way compared to the maintenance cost you have to maintain duplicated code.

Answer (score 0):

“Premature optimization is the root of all evil”

Code duplication is a bad practice and some nanoseconds you gain- I doubt, doesn't worth it.
You can ask compiler to `inline` your code or do the ugly `macro` instead of function and code duplication.

And the answer for overhead is yes and no depends on what and how you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it could have overhead without optimizations enabled, however, as a previous answer stated, code inlining is very aggressive nowadays, compilers do it without asking.

The overhead it could possibly have without optimizations is 2 instructions extra,
1: `mov` `this` into the register
2: `call` the function.

However, optimizations will take care of this.

https://godbolt.org/z/wzhSzG